# Syntax differences between OpenCL compilers

Tags: opencl, intel, nvidia, amd-processor

The following code does compiles with intel/nVidia OpenCL compilers (both based on LLVM):

```
struct Foo{ float2 bar; };
void baz(){
   global struct Foo* foo;
   ((float*)(&foo->bar))[1]=1;
}
```

The AMD compiler says `invalid type conversion`, and accepts the code only with the `global` qualification as:

```
((global float*))(&foo->bar))[1]=1;
```

Which is of them is right according to the specification? (And: should I report the non-conforming compiler(s) somewhere?)

Comment: Probably the AMD compiler, as the nVidia compiler tends to be more lax in general. 

Does the Intel/nVidia compiler accept the code with the global qualification?

Comment: The variant with `global` is accepted by all of them.

Comment: Sorry, we really don't encourage list questions anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenCL spec allows nearly infinite flexibility when it comes to casting pointers.  Basically, the rule is that you the programmer know what you are doing for your particular hardware.  It doesn't address the specific issue of casting across memory spaces, so this should probably be considered undefined behavior.  The differences between vendors is to be expected.

As the CL spec matures over time, you can expect issues like the above to be explicitly addressed, I'd guess.

Comment: The cast is (of course) not meant to be across memory spaces, and intel/nVidia compilers interpret it correctly (i.e. that the target pointer space is the one of pointer being cast). Well, I will start writing down such issues. Would it be a possibility to convert the question to wiki-type question so that such issues would be gathered here?

Comment: Yep - I think you can make it a community wiki question since you were the OP.